# Python. Вывод в столбик

Tags: python, python-3.x, разметка

```
print (t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7)
```

Эта штука вывод в строчку данные человека, подскажите, как заставить выводить эти переменные в столбик? Пробовал вставлять `\n` выдало ошибку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tek = (t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7)
print('\n'.join(tek))
```

Comment: `str.join()` принимает только строки на вход. Пример: `print('\n'.join([str(item) for item in tek]))`

Answer (score 7):

Правильнее переопределить сепаратор (по умолчанию пробел):

```
print (t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7, sep = "\n")
```

Документация по `print`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

Answer (score 0):

Например, так :

```
t1=value1
t2=value2
t3=value3
t4=value4
t5=value5
t6=value6
t7=value7 # "valueX" - это какое-то ваше значение
s=[t1,t2,...,t7]
for i in s:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t1=1  
t2=2  
t3=3  
for i in [t1,t2,t3]:  
 print(i)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Это по сути то же самое, что в [соседнем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/951596/1365)

Comment: Без лишней переменной

Comment: Сути не меняет. Идея одна и та же - собрать все в список, пройти по нему циклом

Comment: Я с этим не спорю